# hibernate criteria query get multiple counts in single query.

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'm wondering if anybody knows how to get multiple counts from a single query using hibernates criteria query?

I have the following query.

```
List<PurchaseRequest> prs = this.session.createCriteria(PurchaseRequest.class).list();
```

within PurchaseRequest, I have a column called current_state. I'd like to query all the PurchaseRequest rows and group the current_states together so I can get a total count of each current_state.

States look like this, creator, authorizer, assignor. etc.

Comment: Do you mean `Select current_state, count(*) From PurchaseRequest Group By current_state` ?

Comment: @AlexS yes, that is exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Criteria criteriaPurchaseRequest=this.session.createCriteria(PurchaseRequest.class);

ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();
projectionList.add(Projections.groupProperty("current_state"));
projectionList.add(Projections.rowCount());

criteriaPurchaseRequest.setProjection(projectionList);

List results = criteriaPurchaseRequest.list();
```

To obtain the results:

```
List results = criteriaPurchaseRequest.list();
Map currentStateMap = new HashMap();
Iterator it=results.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()){
Object obj[]=(Object[])it.next();           
     CurrentState currentState = (CurrentState )obj[0];
    currentStateMap .put(currentState.getDescription().toLowerCase(), (Integer)obj[1]);
}
```

where CurrentState is an object that represents the column current_state (remember, Hibernate is working with objects).

Comment: what would I need to cast results to inorder to get the amount?

Comment: Do you can try this query: "Select current_state, sum(amount), count(*) From PurchaseRequest Group By current_state,amount" ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant the count. What you have seems correct, I'm just not sure how to get it to display the count from the results. If I pull the groupProperty out, I can cast it to a Long, but breaks if I add group back in, I'm assuming it will return the state with the count and would need to create some sort of object where it could be casted to. Just not sure what group property would be.

Comment: I think were close esmoreno, however your code sample doesn't compile, compiling error message "required: array or java.lang.Iterable found: org.hibernate.Criteria" and when I use results, I get this, "incompatible types required: java.lang.Object[]"
  found:    java.lang.Object

Comment: That works and another quick fix to your original code was to use List<Object[]>  with results and then pass results into the for loop. Thanks